# none of fink macports and homebrew useful on lion?

Tags: xcode4, osx-lion

I have an library (flam3) that depends on a few utility libraries from unix (xml2, jpeg, png, z) and I am trying to make an application on Lion that uses it.  I am building with the latest Xcode and when I try to link with the libraries from fink, macports, and homebrew I get the same error:

ld: warning: ignoring file /opt/local/lib/libxml2.a, file was built
for archive which is not the architecture being linked (i386)

and the libraries look different from ones that work:

bash-3.2$ file /sw/lib/libxml2.a
/sw/lib/libxml2.a: current ar archive random library

by comparision

bash-3.2$ file ~/Documents/FLAM3/libflam3.a
/Users/spot/Documents/FLAM3/libflam3.a: Mach-O universal binary with 2
architectures
/Users/spot/Documents/FLAM3/libflam3.a (for architecture x86_64):
 current ar archive random library
/Users/spot/Documents/FLAM3/libflam3.a (for architecture i386):
current ar archive random library

that's the library that I compiled with Xcode.

Is there any way to get Xcode to accept this library?  Is there any way to get fink/macports/homebrew to generate a library that works with Xcode?  Seems like I am "doing it wrong" as these projects would all be useless if everyone had this problem.... but I don't feel like I've done anything unusual.  Help?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your libxml2.a is not built as "Universal binary". I.e. it doesn't contain all necessary architectures (In your case I believe it is i386). You need to ask fink, macports, or homebrew to build/download/install library with all necessary platforms. I know that macports has such flag (I don't remember how it's called). 
The "file" command list all available architectures for .a file only when the file is trully universal (contains two or more of ppc, i386, x86_64), otherwise it only shows the vanilla "ar archive..." message. That confirms your libxml2.a has only one architecture.

The problem is not in Xcode or Lion. Possibly the default link architecture on Lion changed.